# How to interpret this question? Triple integral over region.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Evaluate the triple integrals over the indicated region.

$$\iiint_D (3+2xy)\,dV$$ over the solid hemispherical dome $D$ given by $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq4$ and $z\geq0$.

The surface $3+2xy$ is above and surrounding the hemisphere. What volume would such integration calculate? How do I interpret this question? What is going on here? Sure I could calculate a volume bounded by some x and y values but in this case $0\leq Z\leq2$ but the surface $3+2xy$ barely lies in that $Z$ interval. I am confused

Comment: This is a triple integral... You can interpret it as a 3D volume only if the integrand function is $f = 1$. In general, it would be a 4D volume.

Comment: @PierreCarre so this particular problem is a 4D one?

Comment: It does not mean this is a 4D problem... Integrals exist regardless of being interpreted as volume. I'm just saying that if you want (for some reason) to interpret this integral as a volume, it must be a 4D volume. For instance, when you compute a 1D integral, it can be seen as a 2D area...

Answer (score 1):

This is best computed using spherical coordinates...
$$
\iiint_D (3+2xy) dV = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^2 r^2 \sin \varphi(3 + 2 r \sin \varphi \cos \theta \cdot r \sin \varphi \sin \theta)dr d \varphi d \theta = \cdots = 16 \pi
$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the best way to interpret this problem would be my thinking about what the domain looks like in spherical coordinates. If we convert to we can see that:
$$0\le r\le \theta$$
as this is simply the radius, now we want to rotated the full way around the "vertical" axis to get the whole xy-plane included, which means:
$$0\le\theta\le 2\pi$$
and finally the second angle, now since we only want for $z\ge0$ we will only need:
$$0\le\varphi\le\pi/2$$
Now just convert your formula, using the transformations from cartesian to polar coordinates and remember the $dV$ too and your all set